# Backbone binding to dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

We have a slideshow in our code and I want to generate buttons based on the # of images there are.

I'm iterating across the images for each elements:

```
renderImageButtons: function() {
  images = this.model.attributes.images;
  for (i = 0; i <= images.length; i++) {
    this.$('.image_buttons').append("<li class='"+(i == 0 ? 'selected':'')+"' rel='"+i+"'></li>")
  }
},
```

and attaching the event like so:

```
events: {
  'click .image_buttons li': 'changeImage'
},
```

Now, when I click the li (which is just a little circle), I want to render a specific image in that array, but I'm unsure of how to go about this using Backbone.  Typically I'd parse the rel off the button and then load accordingly, but I'm not sure how to access that information in Backbone or if there is a better way to do this.

Currently I have a rotate image function which auto rotates the images:

```
rotateImage: function() {

  images = this.model.attributes.images;
  image_index = this.model.attributes.current_image_index;

  if (images && image_index != null) {

    image_index++;

    if (image_index > images.length-1 || !images[image_index]) {
      image_index = 0;
    }

    this.model.set({current_image_index: image_index});
  }
},
```

And now I need a changeImage function, but this is where I'm lost:

```
changeImage: function() {
  alert($(this).toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to

- bind a change to your `current_image_index` property to your view `render` method
- have the `changeImage` function pick the `rel` and set the model property

For example :

```
ImagesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click li': 'changeImage'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on("change:current_image_index",this.render,this);
    },
    render: function() {
        var images = this.model.get("images"), selected=this.model.get("current_image_index");

        this.$el.html("");
        _.each(images, function(model,ix) {
            this.$el.append("<li class='"+(ix == selected ? 'selected':'')+"' rel='"+ix+"'>"+ix+"</li>")
        },this);
    },

    changeImage: function(e) {
        var $li=$(e.currentTarget).closest("li");
        this.model.set({current_image_index:$li.attr("rel")});
    }
});

var model=new Backbone.Model({
    images:[{id:1},{id:2}],
    current_image_index:0
});
var view= new ImagesView({
    el: $("ul"),
    model:model
});

view.render();
```

And a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XFTf4/2/

A (probably) cleaner solution would be to handle an image collection and a selected model instead of an index, but that may be overkill for your needs.